# Does the filesize of my Docker apps' image going to be more than the base image?

Tags: windows, docker, containers, virtual-machine

If I dockerize 10 apps that all use this base image from Docker hub: `php:7.3-apache-stretch` (which is about 378MB), will they essentially occupy 3.8GB+ (378MB base image x 10 different apps) of diskspace in my host machine?

Edit: Reason I ask is because if I type `docker image`, this shows up:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                  IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker-test         latest               f941ae2a70f1        31 hours ago        378MB
<none>              <none>               4c71598a1098        31 hours ago        378MB
<none>              <none>               5255a13a71c7        32 hours ago        378MB
<none>              <none>               4979b0dc765c        32 hours ago        378MB
<none>              <none>               97c2190de3d5        32 hours ago        378MB
<none>              <none>               d2e33f282127        32 hours ago        378MB
<none>              <none>               e38ef642324e        32 hours ago        378MB
php                 7.3-apache-stretch   1e9efd9f6779        7 days ago          378MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base image will only be stored once due to the way that docker uses layers to store files. Details of it are best explained in [the documentation.](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#the-copy-on-write-cow-strategy)

In your example the 10 apps would each take up additional space only for size of all of the files you change/add to the image. So if each application is 5MB in size, all 10 would take up `10 * 5MB + 378MB = 428MB`. `(number of apps) * (size of applications) + (base image size)`.

Answer (score 0):

No, the read-only layers - those form your base image as well as those created from your Dockerfiles -  will be shared by all running containers.

For details, see https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#container-and-layers and https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#container-size-on-disk.